# Random number generation from non-uniform distribution in Java

Tags: java, random

i am work in java program and i need to generate random values for my filed!

```
int age;
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
age=random.nextInt(20);
//here i want 30% of 100 to be exactly equal to 15 , and the others are not important for me 

}
```

other example.
I need to generate random values between `0` and `4`. I need zeros to be 40% of the time, the ones to be 20%, and so on.
Any ideas how to do that in simple way?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Read up on what classes java has available to generate random numbers and looked over the documentation of those classes?

Comment: Can you tell a little more about the "etc" part? What comes after 20%, and should these frequencies be exact or the statistical average?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can modify the distribution array as u want. this method return 100 random number with distribution as u desire

```
public static List<Integer> generateRandom(){
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random objGenerator = new Random();
    int distrubution[] = {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,3,4};
    for (int iCount = 0; iCount< 100; iCount++){
        int randomNumber = distrubution[objGenerator.nextInt(10)];
        list.add(randomNumber);
        System.out.println("Random No : " + randomNumber);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Random values from non-uniform distributions are still random values.

Comment: he should ask it that way. now I understand. I will change the answer now.

Comment: its good idea but the results  are not exactly the same percentage that i need because it is take random from the range without condition and i need this condition to get the exact number of zeros that i need , but thanks for your help